# Perl DBI placeholders other than ?s

Tags: sql, perl, placeholder, dbi

I'm trying to write prepare statement for insert SQL and it have many rows to insert at once. So current prepare statement is like below,

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO queues_details (id,keyword,data,flags) VALUES 
                             (?,'penaltymemberslimit','0','0'),
                             (?,'answered_elsewhere','0','0'),
                             (?,'timeoutpriority','app','0'),
                             (?,'timeoutrestart','no','0'),
                             (?,'memberdelay','0','0'),
                             (?,'servicelevel','60','0'),
                             (?,'reportholdtime','no','0'),
                             (?,'ringinuse','yes','0'),
                             (?,'weight','0','0'),
                             (?,'autofill','no','0'),
                             (?,'eventmemberstatus','no','0'),
                             (?,'eventwhencalled','no','0'),
                             (?,'monitor-join','yes','0'),
                             (?,'monitor-format','','0'),
                             (?,'periodic-announce-frequency','0','0'),
                             (?,'queue-thankyou','queue-thankyou','0'),
                             (?,'queue-callswaiting','queue-callswaiting','0'),
                             (?,'queue-thereare','queue-thereare','0'),
                             (?,'maxlen','0','0'),
                             (?,'joinempty','yes','0'),
                             (?,'leavewhenempty','no','0'),
                             (?,'strategy','ringall','0'),
                             (?,'timeout','15','0'),
                             (?,'retry','5','0'),
                             (?,'wrapuptime','0','0'),
                             (?,'announce-frequency','60','0'),
                             (?,'announce-holdtime','no','0'),
                             (?,'announce-position','yes','0'),
                             (?,'queue-youarenext','queue-youarenext','0');");
```

Note that all the `?` values will be same id.

This is complex to maintain and hard to add/remove rows from `prepare` and `execute`.
Is there any kind of numbering method for these placeholders (?s) so I can easily find the rows I need to change.

Thank you!

Comment: That INSERT would be pretty unwieldy even without placeholders. Are you really executing this query multiple times in your script with different sets of ID values?

Comment: At the moment only one ID value at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use only placeholders

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO queues_detail (id,keyword,data,flags) VALUES ";
$sql .= join ', ', ("(?,?,?,?)") x @data;

$dbh->do($sql, $undef, map { $id, @$_ } @data);
```

Or don't use any at all

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO queues_detail (id,keyword,data,flags) VALUES ";
$sql .= join(', ', map { "(" . join(', ', map $dbh->quote($_), $id, @$_) . ")" } @data);

$dbh->do($sql);
```

The above use the following:

```
my @data = (
   [ 'penaltymemberslimit',         '0',                  0 ],
   [ 'answered_elsewhere',          '0',                  0 ],
   [ 'timeoutpriority',             'app',                0 ],
   [ 'timeoutrestart',              'no',                 0 ],
   [ 'memberdelay',                 '0',                  0 ],
   [ 'servicelevel',                '60',                 0 ],
   [ 'reportholdtime',              'no',                 0 ],
   [ 'ringinuse',                   'yes',                0 ],
   [ 'weight',                      '0',                  0 ],
   [ 'autofill',                    'no',                 0 ],
   [ 'eventmemberstatus',           'no',                 0 ],
   [ 'eventwhencalled',             'no',                 0 ],
   [ 'monitor-join',                'yes',                0 ],
   [ 'monitor-format',              '',                   0 ],
   [ 'periodic-announce-frequency', '0',                  0 ],
   [ 'queue-thankyou',              'queue-thankyou',     0 ],
   [ 'queue-callswaiting',          'queue-callswaiting', 0 ],
   [ 'queue-thereare',              'queue-thereare',     0 ],
   [ 'maxlen',                      '0',                  0 ],
   [ 'joinempty',                   'yes',                0 ],
   [ 'leavewhenempty',              'no',                 0 ],
   [ 'strategy',                    'ringall',            0 ],
   [ 'timeout',                     '15',                 0 ],
   [ 'retry',                       '5',                  0 ],
   [ 'wrapuptime',                  '0',                  0 ],
   [ 'announce-frequency',          '60',                 0 ],
   [ 'announce-holdtime',           'no',                 0 ],
   [ 'announce-position',           'yes',                0 ],
   [ 'queue-youarenext',            'queue-youarenext',   0 ],
);
```

Comment: Good solution, thanks! Actually there will be one id at a time, forgot to mention in the question. I also reading bind_ param for this.

Comment: That allows the solution to be simplified, although just a little. Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's up to the database driver. Some of them support other placeholder formats, but most don't. You can look at the docs for yours (e.g. DBD::Pg, DBD::mysql) and see what's available.

Your better options are:

1: Write code to generate the SQL. You're best off using *all* placeholders; then you can start off with a structure like

```
my @data = (
    [ $foo, 'penaltymemberslimit', 0, 0],
    [ $bar, 'answered_elsewhere', 0, 0],
    # ... a bunch more rows
);
```

and follow it up with something like:

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO queues_details (id,keyword,data,flags) VALUES";
my @binds;
for my $row (@data) {
    $sql .= " (?,?,?,?)";
    push @binds, @$row;
}

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$dbh->execute(@binds);
```

2: Use [DBIx::Class](http://p3rl.org/DBIx::Class). If you create a schema with a class for your `queues_details` table, then you can just create one big array of hashes with column names as keys and values as values, and pass that to `populate`, and DBIC will write the insert for you. It might even use a more efficient way of inserting bulk data, for example using a special API or deferring constraints. You also have the option of creating objects and calling `create` on them.

Comment: Your built SQL statement is missing lots of commas.